# How to set/use an empty string value in a variable in Windows XP CMD.EXE command-line?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, cmd.exe

Using SET to set an empty value to a variable works nicely in a Windows XP .CMD script. However, the same SET command behaves differently in the same CMD interpreter when used directly from command-line:

Trying to test it in a CMD.EXE command-line:

```
C:\>set Q=

C:\>echo %Q%
%Q%

C:\>echo "%Q%"
"%Q%"

C:\>set Q=/Q

C:\>echo %Q%
/Q

C:\>echo "%Q%"
"/Q"
```

Trying to test it with a .CMD script like this:

```
set Q=
echo %Q%
echo "%Q%"
set Q=/Q
echo %Q%
echo "%Q%"
```

Running it:

```
C:\>c.cmd

C:\>set Q=

C:\>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\>echo ""
""

C:\>set Q=/Q

C:\>echo /Q
/Q

C:\>echo "/Q"
"/Q"
```

What am I missing?

Is that a nice joke from Redmond, or is there any sane explanation for this difference?

How am I supposed to test lines from a .CMD script when they behave differently when used in a command-line?

How do I properly set a variable to an empty string value in a CMD command-line and how do I reference that variable so that I get that empty string?

Comment: Assigning empty string to variable deletes it. I am wondering if `set` changed its behaviour or the `echo` did since Windows XP. Is `Q` variable listed when you run `set`?

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík: I am talking about Windows XP. `SET` deletes the variable when issued from the command line. It does not delete the variable when used in a .CMD file.

Comment: No, my point is that the `set Q=` command deletes the variable in both scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

I met exactly the same problem in my script.
Currently I didn't find a way to set a variable to empty string.
I just found how to initialize it with one space:

```
set "Var= "
```

Those quotation marks are optional. But they really help to see that space explicitly and preserve it in case of terminal whitespace cleanup procedures.

More information you can find here: [SET command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: I really like this method. The dangling "=" has always bothered me.
It breaks the patterns I look for when visually scanning code for errors.

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr - Problem you got there is that `echo %Q%` expands to `echo`. Use `echo.%Q%`

#### Expanded Answer

`echo` command got 4 behaviors:

- `echo on` - enables echoing commands.
- `echo off` - disables echoing commands.
- `echo` - shows state of echoing commands option.
- `echo ...` - puts `...` and newline on the screen.

If you pass variable to echo as an argument, and it's empty, it will expand to `echo`, and will show something like "ECHO is off."

Many people use `echo.` command to display empty string (read: output newline), but not everybody knows that `echo.` can be used to excplicitly specify that you want output behavior. e.g.:

- `echo.on` - will output `on` and newline
- `echo.off` - will output `off` and newline
- `echo.` - will output newline
- `echo.something` - will output `something` and newline
- `echo.%Q%` - will output contents of `%Q%` whether or not it's ""/"on"/"off" or whatever else.

Keep in mind that there should not be space between `.` and arguments.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Because you "tl;dr" you missed the whole gist of the question. ;-)

Comment: None of this explains why unsetting a variable then attempting to expand it results in no-op at the prompt and empty string in a script.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to set a variable to an empty string.

Comment: Of note: `set command=` with no quotes and no space seems to wrap around to the next line and overall does very odd things to the script.

Answer (score 3):

While you can check whether a variable is empty or not, if you want to **concatenate** a variable to a string with support for empty/null values, a possible workaround would be to **prefix** all your values with a dummy character, and **skip** this character whenever you use this variable:

```
set q=0
set q2=%q:~1%string
```

test:

```
set q=0_
echo %q%
echo %q:~1%concat%q:~1%

set q=0
echo %q%
echo %q:~1%concat%q:~1%
```

The result will be `_concat_` in the first case and `concat` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

@Laszlo Valko: You don't say which CP you use, but I would "fake" the empty variable by using Alt-255, which is an "invisible" character, at least in CP 437. Using your example:

```
@echo off
::The line below contains the invisible character (Alt-255)
echo Q set to "Invisible"
set Q= 
set Q
echo %Q%
echo "%Q%"
echo Q set to Empty
set Q=
set Q
echo %Q%
echo "%Q%"
echo Q set to "/Q"
set Q=/Q
set Q
echo %Q%
echo "%Q%"
```

Using `SET Q` will show you all the variables that start with Q. Try `SET C` and you'll see what I mean. As you can see, when the variable is set to blank, it is deleted. When you do an `ECHO %Q%` the command interpreter thinks you're just saying `ECHO` which then it tells you the state: On or Off. Since I used `@echo off` at the beginning of the script, it reports that echo is Off.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this

```
set v=""
echo v=%v%  //  <--- v=""

if %v% == ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t test everything that works in a `CMD` script in an interactive session. They’re too different. Instead, you have to write short one-off scripts. Remember to do all of the setup in your one-off script (such as turning on delayed expansion).

One of those differences is expanding an empty/undefined variable. Another example is how [`FOR` loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) work. Labels (and [`GOTO`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)) are not usable in interactive mode. I could not find a good resource explaining all of these differences—this list is not exhaustive.

`FOR` interactive:

```
FOR %A IN (1 2 3) DO ECHO %A
```

`FOR` batch file:

```
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) DO ECHO %%A
```